# is AxShDocVw.AxWebBrowser deprecated?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have been having problems with the AxShDocVW.dll in an older project so to recreate the issue, I created a new VB.Net forms project and dropped a WebBrowser control into it.  I noticed that the References contain ShDocVw but not AxShDocVw as in my older project.  Also, when I copied the following line from my older project, it (naturally) did not recognize it.

```
Dim WithEvents MyWebBrowserMain As New AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser
```

Reading through a bunch of pages on the web, I get the impression that AxShDocVw.AxWebBrowser has been deprecated.  Is this true?  And if so, what is the alternative?

Also, I am able to do:

```
Dim WithEvents MyWebBrowserMain As New SHDocVw.WebBrowser
```

but this has limitations for example, I cannot then do MyWebBrowserMain.Location = New Point(...

And I have also discovered:

```
Dim WithEvents MyWebBrowserMain As New System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
```

But is it the right way to do it?  I am confused!!

Thanx,
Anil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no right way... Depends on what you plan to do with the type library

AxSHDocVw: COM proxy wrapper dll generated from aximp or Visual Studio's Windows Forms toolbox, using an old IE type library (IE7 exposes AxWebBrowser from IEFramed.dll, not SHDocVw). Good for Windows Forms apps.

SHDocVw: COM proxy wrapper dll generated from tlbimp or the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog box, using an old IE type library.

If you use Windows Forms, you should be using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser if you target framework is 2.0 or higher, unless the number of extension points does not satisfy your needs, then you need to host the ActiveX version directly.

If your Visual Studio is installed correctly, and you add a new reference to IE's type library, your COM reference is probably changed to use Microsoft's PIA microsoft.mshtml.dll. [Using this reference on IE6 machines is not recommended.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934368)

Comment: Can you please explain "unless the number of extension points does not satisfy your needs" What are extension points?

Comment: Also, once I change all my code to System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser can I delete all refences to AxShDocVw and ShDocVw from my project references?
Thanx for your help

Comment: Depends on the level of customization you need, search "webbrowser customization" in Windows SDK for details. Windows Forms's wrapper control does not let you to change the IDocHostUIHandler implementation and has limited access to the script engine, document, window and elements. If you are only using those features provided by Windows Forms's wrapper control, then you don't need to host the ActiveX by yourself.